# openshift concrete builder quota

Tags: openshift-origin

How does the openshift count the resource quota consumed by specific builder image? (There may be multiple images)

It is created by sti builder, but not openshift cluster itself (k8s exactly).

I know the quota is equal to the sti builder, but would like to know how to count it if we customized the quota (and if I can do that). It looks like the cluster can't count the resource quota (cpu/memory, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Together with quota you can define a scope. See [OpenShift Origin: quota scopes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/quota.html#quota-scopes).

The relevant scope for build and deployment pods is `NonTerminating`. 
Adding this scope to quota definition will constrain it to only build and deployment pods (pods that have `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds is nil` according to docs)

Example definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: slow-builds-and-deployments
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "2" 
    limits.cpu: "1" 
    limits.memory: "1Gi" 
  scopes:
  - NotTerminating
```

The `Terminating` scope on the other side will be applied other pods (pods with `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds >= 0`).